Survival analysis - any benefit to splitting on failure time instead of covariate change for creating time-varying covariates?
When needing to create a time-varying covariate for a survival model, I am accustomed to using (what I understand to be) a counting process structure for my data, where each individual may have multiple rows of data with each row defining a time interval (start, stop time) and containing values of the covariate/s during that interval.
However, in doing more reading on using tvc's I have come across an approach that involves splitting time instead at each unique event time (rather than a covariate change) and creating appropriate time intervals from that instead. But because you are splitting time taking into account ALL events, the dataset can become very large.
I know the Cox model only looks at event times (what about parametric models?), so I guess if you've got the covariate information at that level of granularity it would probably be the better approach?. But otherwise, are there any other benefit to doing this?

That sort of splitting helps if you want to define hazard ratios as explicit functions of time (ie, interactions between a covariate and a function of time). For example, if you want $\text{trt}\times e^{-t}$ as a predictor for a decaying treatment effect, you would strictly need a different value of this predictor at every failure time.  Your software might know how to compute these predictor updates dynamically, but if it doesn't you could do it by splitting the data at every failure time.
I suppose it might also be useful if you want to use the same split dataset for other models that would otherwise require splits in different places.
If you don't have interactions with functions of time in your model then splitting more finely than the covariates actually change won't affect the estimates and will just be slower and use more memory.
